# AVERAGEIF function pulling in non-parameter based data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using an `AVERAGEIF` function to average results based on the selected "Topic Name" defined on the sheet below.

Formula:

`=IF($B5="Primary",AVERAGEIF(Primary!$L$4:$T$107,Testing!C5,Primary!$T$4:$T$107),AVERAGEIF(Secondary!$L$4:$T$107,Testing!$C5,Secondary!$T$4:$T$107))`

[image]

I am running the same formula in columns E and F (just pulling a different column --- this Primary!$T$4:$T$107). They work fine (except column F is multiplying by 10 for some reason?

Anyway, column G's results appear to be populating a division error with 0.

Below is the data being pulled. Only the highlighted cells should be averaged. However, it appears that the other cells (which do not have data) are also being pulled. Am I correct with this assumption? If so, how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This is tough to follow based on the data supplied. We cannot see your row numbers, nor do we know which sheets are you showing. So in your bottom screenshot, should we assume this is the sheet titled "Primary"? If so, why does your AverageIF formula look for "Special Feature" from columns L through T (Primary!$L$4:$T$107)? Why not look for "Special Feature" only in column M? I would start there in troubleshooting this formula.

Comment: @Isolated My apologies. I reuploaded the second image, so it should make more sense. Yes, the bottom sheet was the "Primary" sheet. And, yes, you are correct that it should look only for "Special Feature" from columns L - T.

Comment: So that leads to the question... if cell C5 is always a Topic, then why doesn't the formula only look in column M in the Primary sheet? For example, looking for a topic in a column that shows open rate is asking for problems.

Comment: @Isolated Sorry, I'm not following you.

Comment: I guess it may be fine to have the entire range in the first part of your formula, but when using IF formulas (averageif, sumif, etc), I typically just have the single column in the first part of the formula (like averageif(column m, c5, column t). Easier to read and troubleshoot IMHO. Maybe try that and see if you get 19.3 as your value. Also, if cells E5 and F5 values are averages too, then they appear wrong. Shouldn't the open rate average be 51.5, and the CT rate be 10.0? Is there more data below that we cannot see? If so, then maybe those data are causing the problems with your formula.

Comment: @Isolated Gotcha! Thank you. This helped and is now working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Isolated pointed out in the comments, having the two ranges in AVERAGEIF of unequal size is looking for trouble. There should be a one to one mapping i.e. with AVERAGEIF(A1:A10, "test", B1:B10) the A and B ranges are equal in size. It is saying AVERAGE from column B for each cell in A that is equal to "test". In your case, you include multiple colums in the first range, which in my mind would produce undefined results. I.e.
with AVERAGEIF(A1:B10, "test", C1:C10) it is not clear if A1 or B1 or both should be equal to "test" in order to include C1 in the average - or should it include it twice?

As for why you are getting #DIV0! errors;

- If range is a blank or text value, AVERAGEIF returns the #DIV0! error value, or
- If no cells in the range meet the criteria, AVERAGEIF returns the #DIV/0! error value.

Answer (score 0):

`AVERAGEIF()` is behaving the way some Excel functions do in that it is expanding the array/range it is to examine to match the input array/range.

For example, in this case you are (bizarrely, as there is clearly no reason for doing so due to the data range contents/structure) searching for a term like "Lawn Care" in multiple columns, and the column it will be found in is the SECOND column of that range.

So Excel is then expanding the range which it is to find the values to average to have as many columns as are needed. So while you typed T4:T107 for the range to average with, it is changing it to be nine columns wide (L:T = 9 columns so...). That means the range it is considering when looking for the values to average is actually T4:AB107.

Then, since the matches were found in column TWO of your criteria range, it is taking the values to average from that second column in the new range it created. In other words, if the cell that matches is one column over and three rows down from the search range's upper left cell:  so L4, go one column over so M4, three rows down so M7, it looks in the EXACTLY corresponding place/s in the averaging range (T4:AB107):  so T4, go one column over so U4, three rows down so U7... and so on for all the values it is required to use in the averaging.

Or a different way:  you are forcing it to use an actual range of T:AB not just T:T and since the match values are in the second column, it is using column U, not T, to get values to average.

Looking at your structure and data, the values to match are clearly always going to be in column M. Period. There will be none in column Q, for instance, as "Special Feature" simply won't ever be pulled up in a column intended to hold "Click-Thru Rate" values. To fix this, you must use the appropriate search range, so instead of L4:T107, use only M4:M107.

Things like #DIV0! errors suddenly make sense when you realize that the `FALSE` portion of the `IF()` specifies U:U and so the formula is averaging things in U:AC and using that range's second column so what is being averaged is actually values in V:V so 0's, and `AVERAGE()` can't handle all zeros.

Other oddnesses would have similar explanations. Things like multiplying by 10 for no apparent reason, for example.

Side note:  Another thing to consider about your formula is that while you've gotten just about all the sensible absolute referencing required to be able to copy and paste the formula, if you want to copy across columns, like E to F, then you need to change that "middle C"... gotta have some fun now and then... the one in the `TRUE` branch of the formula, from a bare `C5` to `$C5` or you will be using `D5` in the F column formula (or `B5` if you copied from F to E).

The sad thing about needing to pay close attention to details is that it means missing just one is like the difference between living a happy and the alternative in which you say "I only didn't notice a child running in front of my car once and..." You have to get them ALL right, every time, or none of it ever mattered.